# Why am I getting _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am making a chat assistant app on flutter and I use chat-gpt API in it.A week before it was working perfectly but after sometime I have to change my API key and I only applied the new API key and I didn't touch the code. When I run it the app work perfectly but when i try to ask a question it return me this error and I don't know why its happening because it was running on the same code from past 2 months but now I just change the API key and it returning me this error.

[image]

Here is my API handler code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../constants/api_constant.dart';

class ApiService {
  static Future<String> sendMessage({required String prompt}) async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $API_KEY',
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          "messages": [
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
          ],
          "temperature": 0.7
        }));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final String content =
          jsonDecode(response.body)["model"][0]["messages"]["content"];
      content.trim();
      return content;
    }
    return "Something went Wrong";
  }
}
```

And here is my message field code

```
type herevoid sendTextMessage(String prompt) async {
    setReplyingState(true);
    addToChatList(prompt, true, DateTime.now().toString());
    addToChatList('Typing...', false, 'typing');
    setInputMode(InputMode.voice);
    final response =
        await ApiService.sendMessage(prompt: _messageController.text);
    removeTyping();
    addToChatList(response, false, DateTime.now().toString());
    setReplyingState(false);
  }
```

Well I have check my API key and it says that my app have never use it. Which means its not even hit the API to get the message. I am stuck here don't know where is the problem.

Comment: what is the response structure of the http request?

Comment: Could you please provide an API response?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please use below model error handle.

```
class CompletionsModel {
  String? id;
  String? object;
  int? created;
  String? model;
  String? systemFingerprint;
  List<Choices>? choices;
  Usage? usage;

  CompletionsModel(
      {this.id,
      this.object,
      this.created,
      this.model,
      this.systemFingerprint,
      this.choices,
      this.usage});

  CompletionsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    object = json['object'];
    created = json['created'];
    model = json['model'];
    systemFingerprint = json['system_fingerprint'];
    if (json['choices'] != null) {
      choices = <Choices>[];
      json['choices'].forEach((v) {
        choices!.add(new Choices.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    usage = json['usage'] != null ? new Usage.fromJson(json['usage']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['object'] = this.object;
    data['created'] = this.created;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['system_fingerprint'] = this.systemFingerprint;
    if (this.choices != null) {
      data['choices'] = this.choices!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.usage != null) {
      data['usage'] = this.usage!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Choices {
  String? text;
  int? index;
  Null? logprobs;
  String? finishReason;

  Choices({this.text, this.index, this.logprobs, this.finishReason});

  Choices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    text = json['text'];
    index = json['index'];
    logprobs = json['logprobs'];
    finishReason = json['finish_reason'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['index'] = this.index;
    data['logprobs'] = this.logprobs;
    data['finish_reason'] = this.finishReason;
    return data;
  }
}

class Usage {
  int? promptTokens;
  int? completionTokens;
  int? totalTokens;

  Usage({this.promptTokens, this.completionTokens, this.totalTokens});

  Usage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    promptTokens = json['prompt_tokens'];
    completionTokens = json['completion_tokens'];
    totalTokens = json['total_tokens'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['prompt_tokens'] = this.promptTokens;
    data['completion_tokens'] = this.completionTokens;
    data['total_tokens'] = this.totalTokens;
    return data;
  }
}
```

CompletionsModel Use

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      CompletionsModel completionsModel = CompletionsModel.fromJson(response.body);
      /// as per your need you use
      final String content = completionsModel;
      return content;
    }
```

i refer to the below image output.

[image]